# sine and cosine and difference of angles

Tags: trigonometry

I'm doing a math review, and I am getting a different answer than the guide, and I need some guidance.  Here is the problem:

**Suppose $\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\sin(y)=\frac{1}{2}$, where $x$ terminates in Quad I and $y$ terminates in Quad II. Find $\sin(x-y)$.  The review sheet says the answer is 1.  I come up with $\frac{1}{2}$.**

I use multiple ways to come up with this solution (a couple are listed below) and always get $\frac{1}{2}$.

Method 1:
We can get $x$ and $y$ as:
$$\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}=60^{\circ}=\frac{\pi}{3}$$ $$\sin(y)=\frac{1}{2}=30^{\circ}=\frac{\pi}{6}$$
And then
$$\sin(x-y) = \cos(x)\sin(y)-\cos(y)\sin(x) = \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\right) = \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$$

Method 2:

$$\sin(60^{\circ}-30^{\circ})=\sin(30^{\circ})=\frac{1}{2}$$

So, who's right and who's wrong?  If I'm wrong can someone please help me out?

Comment: The problem statement says $y$ terminates in Quad II. Did you use that fact ?

Comment: It'd be good to write $\cos(x)=\frac{1}2$ implies $x=60^{\circ}=\frac{\pi}3$ rather than what you have now, which states that $\frac{1}2=\frac{\pi}3$.

Comment: I am puzzled. If $x$ is first quadrant and $y$ is second quadrant then $\sin(x-y)$ should be negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are always two (not co-terminal) solutions to $\cos(x)=k$ and similarly for $\sin(x)=k$, where $-1<k<1$. You've not chosen the correct ones. (Though your computations are otherwise correct)

Notice that $\cos(x)=\cos(-x)$, so the two solutions to $\cos(x)=\frac{1}2$ can be found to be $60^{\circ}$ and $-60^{\circ}$ by negating the answer you already found. Similarly, $\sin(x)=\sin(180^{\circ}-x)$, so we have your solution, $30^{\circ}$, and it's supplementary angle $150^{\circ}$. Use the condition on which quadrant the angles must be in to determine which angles are appropriate.

Comment: I agree.  I see how the way I wrote it doesn't indicate what I intended.  Also, when analyzing your answer, the error occurred to me.  Of course, you are correct, and I had that framework in my mind as well, and the way I was working the problem, that didn't appear to apply.  The way I was working it, my mistake was that I was multiplying $\sqrt{3}\times\sqrt{3}$, when I should have been multiplying it by $-\sqrt{3}$.  Doing so gave me the answer of -1.

@whoever it was who edited my markup, thanks.  This is my first post in this stack and appreciate the corrections.